# Normalizing data to new percentage total?

Tags: statistics, percentages, chemistry

I have a range of percentage compositions for chemicals in dry air. At the moment they all total to 100%. For example chemical a=35%, b=20%, c=20%, d=10% and e=15%. If I were to alter the percentage composition of chemical e to 18%, how would I calculate the new percent compositions of a, b, c, and d, given that change in e? Would I divide each of these by 103% to "normalize" them?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using 'percentage' in a reasonable way. If chemical e increases, then the percentage of other chemicals must decrease. How can the 'total percentage' be greater than 100?

What is the absolute measurement (not percentage) of the amount of each chemical? Start from there and recompute percentages.